# display:table export not working correctly

Tags: java, jstl

Below is an example of a table that I am successfully creating with the display:tag construct.  The problem is the export isn't working correctly.  The excel file is saved, but when I open it, all I have is the header row, no data.  I am new to this tag, so it's possible I am missing something simple.  Any ideas?

```
<display:table name="${KualiForm.negotiationActivityHistoryLineBeans}" export="true" id="row" class="datatable-100" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <display:column property="lineNumber" title="History Line #"/>
  <display:column property="activityType" title="Activity Days"/>
  <display:column property="location" title="Location"/>
  <display:column property="startDate" title="Start Date"/>
  <display:column property="endDate" title="End Date"/>
  <display:column property="activityDays" title="Activity Days"/>
  <display:column property="efectiveLocationStartDate" title="Effective Location Start Date"/>
  <display:column property="efectiveLocationEndDate" title="Effective Location End Date"/>
  <display:column property="locationDays" title="Location Days"/>
</display:table>
```

Thanks,
  Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had some misconfiguration for the display:table export to work with our framework. So it was a small collection of quick changes.  Sorry to bother the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the cause of your problem, but have you installed the export filter, as documented [here](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/export_filter.html)?